# Is there any difference between ListLinePlot and ListPlot with Joined to be true?

Tags: plotting

Well, I use both to plot a same set of list and the result looks exact the same:

[image]

So, I'm wondering if these two have any differences. I feel they should, but I need help with the "what".

Comment: There isn't really a difference. But having a `Joined` option in `ListPlot[]` is convenient if one e.g. wants to toggle between the two different visualizations.

Comment: "`ListLinePlot` is a special case of `ListPlot`" is mentioned in the documentation of `ListLinePlot`, in the [Properties and Relations section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html?#528126457).